# Reversing a (soft font) Symbol Set Equation

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm, printing, fonts

HP's soft font Symbol Set format looks like this: `10U, 15H, 1U` (etc.)

To convert this to the appropriate bytes to update the Symbol Set of a soft font, the equation looks like this: `(x * 32) + (y - 64)`

Using 10U as an example, here is how X and Y would be defined: `(10 * 32) + (85 - 64) = 341`

> *Note, `85` is the decimal equivalent of `U`*

`341` ends up being my decimal value, which is the equivalent of `10U`.

So a user can enter `10U`, and I could easily update the value of a symbol set in a font. However, I'm trying to find a way to read the value `341`, and somehow determine that `10U` is the symbol set. Is it possible to reverse this equation?

I've never asked a question like this, so please let me know how I can help clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, I actually figured it out.

While I am seeing 341 as my value, that is actually a result of its own. This is actually the computer taking two 8 byte values, and doing the math for me by converting them to a 16 bit integer.

> Value 1: 320
>
> Value 2: 21
>
> Computer is displaying: 341

So all I need to do:

> Take the first value: 320 \ 32 to get 10
>
> Take the second value: 21 + 64 = 85 (U)

There it is: 10U